# How to hide statusbar in windows tablet 8.1 cordova application?

Tags: cordova

i have working  on window table 8   hide the  status bar  but not finished here problem is when click  show the page that page is scrolling  that is my problem so  i need hide the status bar through out my cordova windows tablet application   please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

In MainPage.xaml

replace this:

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
```

To:

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```